# Teradata date difference

Tags: function, teradata, period

Hi i have used the following query for finding date difference ,but i am getting one hour difference between source and target, but when i checked manually for the dates in excel value is matching.

```
select  a.CASE_ID as CASE_ID,a.FST_QUE_TIME_IN_SECStest   as        
FST_QUE_TIME_IN_SECS from  (select 
distinct CC.CASE_ID as CASE_ID,
CC.CASE_STS_CD,
CC.CRT_DTTM_PST,
CC.REC_DTTM_PST,
MIN(case when CC.CASE_STS_CD ='Open' then CC.CRT_DTTM_PST  end )as  
FST_QUE_TIME_IN_SECS1,
MIN(case when CC.CASE_STS_CD ='Open' then CC.REC_DTTM_PST end ) as  
FST_QUE_TIME_IN_SECS2,
(FST_QUE_TIME_IN_SECS1-FST_QUE_TIME_IN_SECS2 DAY(4) to SECOND) as  
FST_QUE_TIME_IN_SECS,
cast(extract (day from FST_QUE_TIME_IN_SECS) * 86400 +  extract(hour from    
FST_QUE_TIME_IN_SECS) * 3600 +   extract(minute from   
FST_QUE_TIME_IN_SECS)    
*60 +   extract(second from FST_QUE_TIME_IN_SECS) as INTEGER)as   
FST_QUE_TIME_IN_SECStest 

FROM EDW_KATAMARI_T.CNTCT_CASE   CC 
where CC.CASE_ID='14424461'
group by 1,2,3,4
)
a
where a.FST_QUE_TIME_IN_SECStest is not NULL 

minus

select 
CASE_ID, 
FST_QUE_TIME_IN_SECS

from EDW_KATAMARI_T.CNTCT_CASE_SUMRY 
where  CASE_ID='14424461'
```

Comment: Which calculation is incorrect the interval (`FST_QUE_TIME_IN_SECS`), the arithmetic (`FST_QUE_TIME_IN_SECStest`), or both?

Comment: FST_QUE_TIME_IN_SECS is giving 1 hour difference